# Can't load image in swf

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, loader

I get error with load image into swf file. Here is my code:

```
    private var loader:Loader = new Loader(  );
    public function Battle()
    {
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com.vn/images/srpr/logo4w.png"));
    }
    private function onComplete(event:Event):void
    {

        addChild(loader);
     }
```

e very thing is OK, logo of Google appeared. But I need to manipulate pixel the image have loaded. I add a image Bitmap :

```
    private var loader:Loader = new Loader(  );
    private var image:Bitmap;

    public function Battle()
    {
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com.vn/images/srpr/logo4w.png"));
    }
    private function onComplete(event:Event):void
    {

        image =  Bitmap(loader.content);
        this.addChild(image);

    }
```

There is nothing appear. I can't find any solution on internet. I try and detect :

```
private function onComplete(event:Event):void
    {

        image =  Bitmap(loader.content);
        //after above line, rest of function never run
        addChild(image);   // <-- no run @@
        trace("this no run"); // <-- no run @@
    }
```

I use Flash Builder 4 and have no error or any warning. 
Can somebody show me a solution, please?
Thank for reading.

Comment: have you tried to add other handlers like IOErrorEvent, or SecurityErrorEvent?

Comment: Make sure that the Class name and Constructor with the same name (`Battle`). your code definitely no problem.

Comment: I suppose you useing regular (not debug) version of Flash player. In debug player you will get an error `SecurityError: Error #2122`

Answer (score 0):

You can't access pixel data of an image if image is in different domain than your application (and there is no `crossdomain` policy file)

Answer (score 0):

1 You need crossdomain.xml on Google site :)

2 You need use checkpolicy:

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.checkPolicyFile = true;
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com.vn/images/srpr/logo4w.png"), context);
```

but it works only if Google add crossdomain.

3 You can use little serverside proxy on your domain. Flash call proxy to get file with your url, proxy download it and return to flash...